# How do I make couchDB work on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, nosql, couchdb

Is there the way to have couchDB hosted on Heroku?

I have tried two buildpacks, but one is no longer available and the other is not working.

If there's no other way Is it possible to write my own buildpack, if so where should I start?